# SQL - Error with Sum(Case

Tags: sql, oracle

I have searched a bunch of examples which were quite helpful but in creating my query but I am having trouble with one part of the query...

Sorry for not being able to provide the complete table structure. Here is a working query...

```
select i.spl_instr_code_1 LW,
        SUM((d.units_ordered/i.std_sub_pack_qty) - (d.units_rcvd/i.std_sub_pack_qty)) as "Booked"
From wmdbadmin.item_master i, wmdbadmin.cust_po_appt c, wmdbadmin.po_hdr h,
    wmdbadmin.po_dtl d, wmdbadmin.appt_sched a, wmdbadmin.vendor_master v, 
    wmdbadmin.sys_code s 
where h.ref_field_2 = 'N' and
    c.appt_nbr = a.appt_nbr (+) and c.po_nbr = h.po_nbr and
    h.po_nbr = d.po_nbr and i.sku_id = d.sku_id and
    h.vendor_master_id = v.vendor_master_id and s.code_id = a.stat_code and 
    s.rec_type = 'S' and s.code_type = '628' and s.code_desc<>'Scheduled' and 
    a.stat_code <= '90' and ((to_char(a.sched_date_time,'YYYYMMDD')>= '20150401'
    and to_char(a.sched_date_time, 'YYYYMMDD')<='20150401'))
group by i.spl_instr_code_1  
order by i.spl_instr_code_1 asc
```

I tried to alter the above by changing...

```
SUM((d.units_ordered/i.std_sub_pack_qty) - (d.units_rcvd/i.std_sub_pack_qty)) as "Booked"
```

to...

```
SUM( case when s.code_desc<>'Checked In' then (d.units_ordered/i.std_sub_pack_qty) else (d.units_rcvd/i.std_sub_pack_qty) end ) as “Booked”
```

but I get the following error and I am uncertain what the error means and can not figure out how to correct it...

> #Source: OraOLEDB Number: -2147467259 Description: ORA-00972: identifier is too long SQL State: Native Error: 972
>
> #Failed to Open the Recordset [hr=2147500037 (0x80004005)]
>
> # Source: ADODB.Recordset Number: 3704 Description: Operation is not allowed when the object is closed. SQL: select i.spl_instr_code_1 LW, SUM( case when s.code_desc<>'Checked In' then (d.units_ordered/i.std_sub_pack_qty) else (d.units_rcvd/i.std_sub_pack_qty) end ) as “Booked” From wmdbadmin.item_master i, wmdbadmin.cust_po_appt c, wmdbadmin.po_hdr h, wmdbadmin.po_dtl d, wmdbadmin.appt_sched a, wmdbadmin.vendor_master v, wmdbadmin.sys_code s where h.ref_field_2 = 'N' and c.appt_nbr = a.appt_nbr (+) and c.po_nbr = h.po_nbr and h.po_nbr = d.po_nbr and i.sku_id = d.sku_id and h.vendor_master_id = v.vendor_master_id and s.code_id = a.stat_code and s.rec_type = 'S' and s.code_type = '628' and s.code_desc<>'Scheduled' and a.stat_code <= '90' and ((to_char(a.sched_date_time,'YYYYMMDD')>= '20150331' and to_char(a.sched_date_time, 'YYYYMMDD')<='20150331')) group by i.spl_instr_code_1 order by i.spl_instr_code_1 asc
>
> # Source: SQLBuilder.clsSQLBuilder Number: 25004 Description: Closed recordset object returned from database.
>
> #Failed on call to GetRecords on Business Object. at line: 385
>
> #Failed on call RefreshDataGrid.

Comment: Atleast try formatting the post.

Comment: Did you really change from ASCII double quotes to curly quotes around the `Booked` alias? That's not allowed. Or is that just a copying error in SO?

Comment: I am not an expert on this at all... I just copied the working query and tried to make the modification. As far as the quotes go... I didn't make any change to them from the original working query authored by someone else.

Comment: But you *did* change the quotes, @G-J.  They differ between the working and non-working queries you posted.  The question is whether they were changed in the query you actually ran, or only in what you posted in your question.

Comment: You guys are awesome... I actually have both the queries in Google Docs. Although the quotes look the same in Google Docs and when I paste them to SQL, they apparently are not. I copied the quotes from the first to the second and it works!. The only place the visual difference shows is on this page which I did not notice until you pointed it out.